# How to purchase a set of legal docs for my new forum

Tags: privacy

I am about to launch a forum, and am in need of the "entire package" of legal docs to keep me best defended from trouble with people who will get their feelings hurt by someone talking negatively about their company etc. Immediately I think of a TOS, Privacy Policy etc.  I'm sure there is more to think about for a robust protection of the forum owner.  Maybe even the best construct of a legal entity wrapper on the entire effort, etc.

I am hoping this type of legal service has become somewhat "standard" in terms of exactly what one needs.  What might that be called?  What is the category of legal service I would even ask for?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer; one will know what you need, becuase that's what they do..

Comment: I do not recommend it at all but, of course, you can search for "terms of service template" etc.

Answer (score 1):

### This service is called “a lawyer”

It’s been more or less standardized for about 400 years, give or take a century or so.

Your lawyer will be able to give advice on legal matters and draft legal documents.

You probably should also use the services know as:

- an accountant, who deals with bookkeeping and taxation,
- a banker, who deals with finance and banking,
- an engineer, who builds platforms and software, and
- a marketer, who deals with marketing.